# how to have autocomplete c++ in atom editor

Tags: c++, autocomplete, atom-editor

How can I have autocomplete in atom for c++ like codeblock when code, for example when include header  for example when I type "`i`" it return to "`iostream, iomanip.....`" when I type " `sq`" it have "`sqrt`", when type "`back`"  it have `back_inserter`. In short, how to have to code complete like code block, I used `autocomplete-clang` package but maybe I need config something but mine useless, it not have autocomplete like I said, thanks all.